# unable to execute roscore on raspberry pi

Tags: ros, raspberrypi, roscore, raspbian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
i am newbie to ROS and raspberry pi. I installed ros on my raspberry pi by following the instructions given on ros site.
Now when i try to run roscore command on raspberry i get this error:

"Unable to contact my own server at [http://raspberrypi:48182/].
This usually means that the network is not configured properly.

Unhandled exception in thread started by
sys.excepthook is missing
lost sys.stderr"

Please help me to sort out this problem

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64233/unable-to-execute-roscore-on-raspberry-pi/) by [Bhargav](https://answers.ros.org/users/5029/bhargav/) on ROS Answers with karma: 72 on 2013-06-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Try adding this at the top of your */etc/hosts*

```
127.0.0.1   raspberrypi
```

Also, if that doesn't solve it, as there are different places on the ROS site that explain how to install it on the RPi (I know...), it would help to know which instructions you followed, what was the exact page?

---

Originally posted by [po1](https://answers.ros.org/users/4425/po1/) with karma: 411 on 2013-07-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0